# Understanding generics syntax in java - generic types implementing multiple interfaces as parameters

Tags: java, generics

I have some interfaces (and for completeness two dummy classes, so you may copy the code into your ide)

```
public interface ItfA
{
  String getA();
}

public interface ItfB
{
  String getB();
}

public class MyClassAdapter
{
    public Object getValue(Object bean)
    {
        return null; // override to do something useful
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MyClassAdapter mca)
    {
        // do something useful with it
    }
}
```

And I have some functions using these as parameters (looks a bit weird, but that's how I have to use them (I can't change the `MyClassAdapter`)) ...

```
public <T extends ItfA> MyClass getMyClass(final Class<T> itf)
{
    return new MyClass(new MyClassAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object bean)
            {
                return itf.cast(bean).getA();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

So I can call this `getMyClass` only with classes implementing interface `ItfA` - otherwise the compiler will complain.

Alternatively I can rewrite this method without the named generic type T as ...

```
public MyClass getMyClass2(final Class<? extends ItfA> itf)
{
    return new MyClass(new MyClassAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object bean)
            {
                return itf.cast(bean).getA();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

In some cases I need classes as parameters that implement more than one interface - this will work:

```
public <T extends ItfA & ItfB> MyClass getMyOtherClass(final Class<T> itf)
{
    return new MyClass(new MyClassAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object bean)
            {
                return itf.cast(bean).getA() + itf.cast(bean).getB();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

but this one doesn't work

```
public MyClass getMyOtherClass2(final Class<? extends ItfA & ItfB> itf)
{
    return new MyClass(new MyClassAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object bean)
            {
                return itf.cast(bean).getA() + itf.cast(bean).getB();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I don't get the difference between these two kinds of generic parameters (`<T extends ItfA>` before the method name and using `Class<T>` in the parameters opposed to using `Class<? extends ItfA>` in the parameters) - why do both types work with one interface, and why does one work with two interfaces, but the other one doesn't.

Any hints? To me, the second variant is a bit more readable, so I'd prefer that, but I don't get it to work with multiple interfaces ...

Comment: Not being able to adjust `MyClassAdapter` really neuters the power that you can get with generics here.  You're forced to cast regardless of what you do and generics do that cast at *compile* time.  The casts you're doing *may* work at compile time but could likely blow up at runtime.

Comment: You know all of these are equivalent to the reflection-free `new MyClass(new MyClassAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object bean)
            {
                return ((ItfA) bean).getA();
            }
        }
    );`, right?

Comment: @LouisWasserman:  Suppose a `Class<ItfB>` came through...

Comment: @Makoto: Yes?  Then exactly the same `ClassCastException` would occur in both cases.

Comment: Are you asking why `<T extends ItfA & ItfB>` is different from `<? extends ItfA & ItfB>` (which doesn't work)?

Comment: @LouisWasserman:  Actually...that's true.  Not sure why I skimmed over that `getB()` only existed in `ItfB` anyway.  That one's on me.

Comment: @MickMnemonic - yes, exactly that's the question: what's the difference ...

Comment: @Makoto - it's all about type safety at compile time, so there's no possibility to get it blown at runtime

Comment: ...which is why I stand by my original remarks @outofmind.  You're getting quite *useless* checks  at compile time, given that even though your first example may be syntactically correct, nothing you currently have today implements both `ItfA` and `ItfB`, which may be more what you're looking for anyway.

Comment: @Makoto - the point is that changing a method name (without using these interface pattern) will result in ClassCastExceptions at runtime while using these interface will guarantee that the compiler will check before the program is started and prevents the `MyClassAdapter.getValue()` will ever be called with anything that doesn't implement `ItfA`. That's what type safety is about, nothing useless at all. Even if you think this is useless in the specific context - the question was about the difference of TypeParameter and TypeArgument as answered by lexicore below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [TypeParameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2), [TypeArgument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) can't have several bounds, so `<? extends ItfA & ItfB>` is not valid.

Here's my guess on *why* it is so.

I think the reason is that TypeArgument needs to be specific to be useful. For instance in case of `Class<T>` the method `cast` returns `T`, you should be able to declare a variable of that type and assign the result to it.

TypeArgument can be:

1. ClassType
2. InterfaceType
3. TypeVariable
4. ArrayType
5. Wildcard

Cases 1-4 are not problematic, there you always have some specific type or type variable.

In case of the Wildcard we have WildcardBounds for instance `<? extends IntfA>`.

If you allow just one upper bound, then you have something specific for `T`. In case of `Class<? extends IntfA>` you can assume that `cast` returns `InfA`.

If you allow more that one upper bound `<? extends ItfA & ItfB>` then the question is, what could you use for `T` then? Since you in general case you don't have any specific type for `T`, the best you can do is `Object` which is not very useful.

I think this is the reason language authors did not allo multiple upper bounds for wildcard type arguments.

Comment: Ok, so in one case the parameter has a named type T (which implements ItfA & ItfB), in the other case there's no type for the parameter. With just one interface there's either a named type T (which implements ItfA), or the type ItfA for the parameter - ok, that makes sense, thanks.